# A way to flat an array recursively on MDN

Tags: javascript, arrays

MDN provides [a way to flat an array recursively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#reduce_concat_isArray_recursivity):

```js
function flatDeep(arr, d = 1) {
   return d > 0 ? arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatDeep(val, d - 1) : val), [])
                : arr.slice();
}
```

Why we need `arr.slice()` to get a copy? I think just `arr` is OK, is there any problem with just using `arr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's intended to exactly emulate the behavior of `Array.prototype.flat`, which returns a *new* array even if there's nothing to be flattened:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
console.log(arr === arr.flat());
```

The `.slice` isn't necessary to produce a flattened array, it's just there to create a new array reference just in case there's no recursion to do.

The requirement of the creation of a new array is described in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.flat), and in [FlattenIntoArray](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-flattenintoarray). Even if there aren't any elements to flatten, a new array is created by assigning all properties and values of the old array to the new array. ("Repeat, while sourceIndex < sourceLen: (assign property `origArr[sourceIndex]` to new array)")

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no problem if you don't modify the returned value.

However the behaviour is confusing if the returned value is modified, either by an unknowing user or by accident.
A function that *sometimes* returns a clone and *sometimes* returns a reference makes it harder to debug,
and is most likely considered an antipattern.

Since there is no standard for indicating whether a returned array is mutable in JavaScript,
MDN most likely considered it is better to be safe and consistent